# Как изменить статус выполненного потока на NEW?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Как известно, при создании потока он приобретает статус `NEW`, а когда завершит своё выполнение - приобретет статус `TERMINATED`.

- Как создавался поток?

Поток был создан с помощью создания отдельно класса, назовем его `class SecondStream extends Thread`, который `наследуется от класса Thread`:

```
class SecondStream extends Thread{
    public void run(){
        try {
            if(!isInterrupted()){   //проверяем, не нужно ли завершить поток, если нет, идем дальше
                this.deleteDuplicateFromStream();    //тут запускаем метод в данном классе, который выполняет нужные мне действия
            }
            else throw new InterruptedException();      //иначе бросаем исклчение
        } catch (InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println("Дочерний поток исполнения прерван.");
        }
    }
}

public void startStream() throws InterruptedException{
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    this.start();    //запускаем поток
}
```

- Как запускался данный поток (`SecondStream`)?

Данный поток `SecondStream` запускался из класса `Main`:

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    //объявляем создание потока
    SecondStream ss = new SecondStream();

    try{
        ss.startStream();
    } catch (InterruptedException e){
        System.out.println("Главный поток исполнения прерван.");
    }
}
```

- Задача:

Необходимо опять запустить данный поток.

- Решение\Вопрос:

**UPD 1 (РЕШЕНО):**

Как изменить статус данного потока опять на `NEW` (и возможно ли это сделать?), чтобы он мог начать опять своё выполнение? Потому, что если попытаться запустить поток со статусом `TERMINATED` выпадет исключение `IllegalThreadStateException`.

**UPD 2:**

Каким образом запустить опять данный поток `SecondStream`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Статус TERMINATED является конечным статусом в жизненном цикле потока. Из конечного статуса запустить поток невозможно.

**UPD.**

`SecondStream` имплементируйте интерфейсом `Runnable`.

Затем запускайте потоки, можно анонимно, можно явно.

Например:

```
Thread secondStreamThread = new Thread(new SecondStream());
secondStreamThread.start();
```

Comment: Дополнил топик, посмотрите, пожалуйста (хотелось бы услышать варианты ответа на вопрос **UPD 2**)

Comment: @n199a обновил.

Answer (score 1):

Никак.
Из [java доков](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start%28%29):

> It is never legal to start a thread more than once. In particular, a thread may not be restarted once it has completed execution.

Comment: Дополнил топик, посмотрите, пожалуйста (хотелось бы услышать варианты ответа на вопрос **UPD 2**)